# Redirecting aws load balancer traffic to azure VM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, azure-load-balancer

I have a tomcat ec2 server behind AWS application load balancer with the example domain http://sourceplatform.xyz.com/

sourceplatform.xyz.com points to the hostname of the load balancer, which based on rules directs traffic to target group.

I want to deploy another web app with the suffix http://sourceplatform.xyz.com/visual.
I could use path based rules in aws load balancer, but due to decisions beyond my control I need to deploy any new app to Azure.

Is there a way I can make AWS load balancer redirect path based traffic(for /visual/) to Azure load balancer?
We have peering setup between AWS and Azure and all communication is on private network(There's no public network involved)

Comment: Sounds like API Gateway would be a more appropriate tool than an ALB here, although I don't know how the Azure peering works in either case.

Comment: Does azure LB give you static private ip accessible from ALB's vpc?

Comment: @Marcin, It does. But the rules only allow specifying instance to which traffic needs to be redirected. from what I know

Comment: If you have private ip, add your azure lb ip as `ip type` target.